# Which statistical test should I use to evaluate my hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, ordinal-data

My hypothesis states that "Multiplayer Game is more enjoyable than the single-player game" and lets suppose I have 2 variables one categorical with two categories and the other one is ordinal (Likert scale 1 to 5). Which test should I use to prove my hypothesis?

[image]

Comment: (a) It seems you give no data for the variable with two categories. So, we can comment specifically only on the Likert variable. (b) You can 'test' a hypothesis $H_0$ against an alternative $H_a,$ which may give an idea whether to believe the hypothesis or the alternative, but "prove" is not really the right word to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Likert data as below, for
Multi-player and Single-player games,
you might try a Wilcoxon rank sum test in R.

```
multi = c(5,4,5,4,4,4,4)
singl = c(3,2,2,1,1,1,1)
wilcox.test(multi, singl)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test 
    with continuity correction

data:  multi and singl
W = 49, p-value = 0.00147
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(multi, singl) :
 cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

The warning message is because, for small sample sizes,
this test cannot give exact P-values for data with
multiple tied observations (as in your data).

However, in your example all of the Multi-player
Likert scores are 4 and above and all of the Single-player
scores are 3 and below. The probability that out of 14
scores 7 with high values would be in one group and 7 with
low values would be in the other group is $2/{14 \choose 7} =  0.0005827506,$ which is the P-value of an exact permutation test. So you have strong evidence that the Likert ratings
for the Multi-player game are higher.

In R, this can be formalized as a [Fisher Exact Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)
on the $2\times 2$ data table `TAB` with rows for Single/Multi
and columns for High/Low scores.

```
TAB = cbind(c(0,7),c(7,0)); TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    7
[2,]    7    0
fisher.test(TAB)

         Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TAB
p-value = 0.0005828
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.0000000 0.1991716
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```